# Input dimension issue of Conv1D network

Tags: python, pandas, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

As I am new in Deep Learning field, I am facing a strange issue regarding the input shape of my Convolutional network (1D). The input is normalized values of 13 features and total 7866 samples are available

> x_train_shape (7866, 13)

The target is 0 or 1 for each features.

> y_train.shape (7866, 13)

I am using following simple 1D conv network just to see how it performs.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1,
                 activation='relu', input_shape=(13,1)))

model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(13, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20, verbose=0)
```

It shows the summary of the network but also raises this error:

> Error when checking input: expected conv1d_1_input to have 3
> dimensions, but got array with shape (7866, 13)

I tried to implement different solutions from [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6242) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59106391/using-conv1d-error-when-checking-input-expected-conv1d-input-to-have-3-dimensi) . So when

> input_shape = (13,)

is used, it raises a different error like this:

> Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv1d_1: expected ndim=3, found
> ndim=2

Can anyone please enlighten me what is the proper input_shape for this network and why?
N.B. x_train and y_train are in pandas dataframe format. Is that causing any issues, should I have to convert it to another format?

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the `input_shape` argument the same, you should add a dimension to your input, or "*unsqueeze*" it.

```
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, 0)
```

Its shape will now be:

```
(7866, 13, 1)
```

Comment: I do not think it is usable because x_train is a pandas dataframe, it is not possible to expand using np.expand_dims function.

Comment: You have to turn it into a numpy array by using x_train.values, keras turns it into an array for training anyway

Comment: This is what I did to convert the pandas datafram into numpy
    
    `x_train_array = x_train.values
    x_train_array = np.expand_dims(x_train_array, 0)
    y_train_array = y_train.values
    y_train_array = np.expand_dims(y_train_array, 0)`

Input layer:
`model.add(Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1,
                     activation='relu', input_shape=(13,1)))`

Fit the model:
 `model.fit(x_train_array, y_train_array, epochs=20, verbose=0)`

But it shows error :
**Error when checking input: expected conv1d_1_input to have shape (13, 1) but got array with shape (7866, 13)**

Comment: Don't do it to the target array though

Comment: Now I changed y_train and y_test to numpy but kept the dimension same. The error is still the same : Error when checking input: expected conv1d_1_input to have shape (13, 1) but got array with shape (7866, 13)

Am I doing wrong in the input shape or the input data?

Answer (score 0):

> Reshape your training data as follows:
> Then run your model

```
x_train.reshape(7866, 13,1)
```